# CakePHP and MongoDB: Undefined index length when saving data

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am on Cake 2.3.5 and using this: https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb

**DB Config**

```
public $mongo = array(
    'datasource' => 'Mongodb.MongodbSource',
    'database' => 'hello_forms',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 27017,
    'persistent' => 'true',
);
```

**The model:**

```
<?php
class Form extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Form';
    var $primaryKey = '_id';
    var $useDbConfig = 'mongo';
    var $useTable = false;

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A list name is required.',
            'required' => true
        ),
    );

    public function schema() {
        $this->_schema = array(
            '_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => NULL, 'length' => 40, 'key' => 'primary'),
            // '_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'key' => 'primary',  'length' => 40),
            'name' => array('type' => 'string'),
            'unique_string' => array('type' => 'string'),
            'account_id' => array('type' => 'integer'),
            'description' => array('type' => 'string'),
            'success_text' => array('type' => 'string'),
            'success_redirect' => array('type' => 'string'),
            'created'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
            'modified'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
            'form_elements' => array(
                array(
                    'field_description' => array('type' => 'string'),
                    'field_label' => array('type' => 'string'),
                    'field_type' => array('type' => 'string'),
                    'weight' => array('type' => 'integer'),
                    'date_format' => array('type' => 'string'),
                    'is_required' => array('type' => 'boolean'),
                    'allow_duplicates' => array('type' => 'boolean'),
                    'meta' => array(
                        array(
                            'meta_label' => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'meta_default_value' => array('type' => 'string'),
                            'meta_checked' => array('type' => 'boolean')
                        )
                    )
                ),
            )
        );
        return $this->_schema;
    }
}
```

**The error:**

```
<b>Notice</b> (8)</a>: Undefined index: length [<b>CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php</b>, line <b>1793</b>]
```

I have been trying to figure this for a long time and I am out of ideas. I found this one: https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3138-undefined-index-length-on-modelsave but I do not know how to "process" the information on that page.

Did I miss something when declaring the schema? I have tried to put "length" for all the fields and I still get that error. What gives?

EDIT: Just for clarification, since it is only a `Notice`, the data is still being saved into MongoDB. It is messing with my JSON data however.

Comment: can you please check whether `'key' => 'primary'` will be a write syntax to define a key primary. Rather it would be `'primary' => true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out a few minutes after I submitted this question X_X

It turns out, I was using the "old way" to declare the schema. I was using Mark Story's example: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-mongodb-with-cakephp and it is out-dated. The correct way is this: https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/cake2.2/samples/Model/Post.php

TL;DR I should read the comments if the post is 2 years old :|

```
<?php
class Form extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Form';
    var $primaryKey = '_id';
    var $useDbConfig = 'mongo';

    var $mongoSchema  = array(
        'name' => array('type' => 'string'),
        'unique_string' => array('type' => 'string'),
        'account' => array('type' => 'integer'),
        'description' => array('type' => 'string'),
        'success_text' => array('type' => 'string'),
        'success_redirect' => array('type' => 'string'),
        'created'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
        'modified'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
        'form_elements' => array(
            array(
                'field_description' => array('type' => 'string'),
                'field_label' => array('type' => 'string'),
                'field_type' => array('type' => 'string'),
                'weight' => array('type' => 'integer'),
                'date_format' => array('type' => 'string'),
                'is_required' => array('type' => 'boolean'),
                'allow_duplicates' => array('type' => 'boolean'),
                'meta' => array(
                    array(
                        'meta_label' => array('type' => 'string'),
                        'meta_default_value' => array('type' => 'string'),
                        'meta_checked' => array('type' => 'boolean')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'A list name is required.',
            'required' => true
        ),
    );
}
```